# Applying a Minipage Fix to a Tikzpicture Environment to Center the Last Line of a Title

Tags: tikz-pgf, titles, paragraphs, center

I am trying to center the last line of a title in a tikzpicture with

`\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}`

which was suggested to me in a previous post when working with a minipage environment.

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength\drop % To drop the start of the paragraph below the top of the picture.
\setlength\drop{15pt}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \shade node[preaction={fill=black,opacity=.5,},fill=yellow!35, inner sep=5mm]
  {\parbox{0.87\textwidth}{\fontsize{12}{13}\selectfont
    \vspace{\drop}%
    \hangindent=\dimexpr 0.2\textwidth+\columnsep\relax
    \hangafter=-4
    \noindent\llap{\raisebox{\dimexpr \drop+0.6\baselineskip-\height}[0pt][0pt]% overlap indentation
      {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-c}}\hspace{\columnsep}}%
      \leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}\textbf{\textcolor{red}{TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE (PART TO BE CENTERED)}} \\[-5pt]~\smallskip\\
      \textbf{\textit{\lipsum[2]}}}} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

As you can see, my placement of the above series of commands centers the last line of the contents of the tikzpicture.

So, I figured that I would make use of some braces to try and restrict them to the title only; but, when I replace `\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}\textbf{\textcolor{red}{TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE (PART TO BE CENTERED)}}` with `{\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}\textbf{\textcolor{red}{TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE (PART TO BE CENTERED)}} }` and execute the program, it is as if I did not even incorporate the list of centering commands at all:

[image]

I have tried other things, such as creating a minipage environment for the title and applying `\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}` after `\begin{minipage}{}`. That works.---But it also throws off the alignment of the tikzpicture, forcing me to tweak the numerical values of other paramenters in the code, which is not a solution for I have been producing many of these tikzpictures, which potential amounts to continually tweaking the parameters each time I create a new box of this type.

So, I ask:

QUESTION: Where may the string `\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}` be placed in the program code so that the last line of the title, (PART TO BE CENTERED) in this case, is centered relative to the first line and everything else in the tikzpicture remains positioned as it is?

Thank you.

**Emphasis** Aside from the centering of the last title line, I need everything in the display to remain *as is*, especially the text wrapping, for the rectangular image I am actually using is significantly more oblong than the above picture suggests; e.g.,

[image]

Comment: well this comes back to the comment I made on your last question. You can only use the `\parfillskip` centering on the last line of the paragrap[h. You (based on an earlier question) are setting all the text including the title and the lipsup as a _single_ paragraph with a complicated shape. You could trivially set this with the image, then the title paragraph then the lipsum paragraph, then use this method to centre the last line of the title, unless you have remaining reasons for the `\hangindent`

Comment: as it is your setting of `\parfiillskip` is discarded at the `}` so not used as the value at teh end of the paragraph is what counts.

Answer (score 2):

I think you intended something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\vspace*{-4cm}
\enlargethispage{2cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \shade node[preaction={fill=black,opacity=.5,},fill=yellow!35, inner sep=5mm, text width=.87\textwidth,align=justify]
  {%
\fontsize{12}{13}\selectfont
\leavevmode\smash{\raisebox{-2.5\baselineskip}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-c}}}\hfill
\parbox[t]{.75\textwidth}{%
\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}\textbf{%
\textcolor{red}{(PART TO BE CENTERED)}}\strut
\par
\xdef\tlines{\the\prevgraf}}
\par
\vspace{\baselineskip}%
\ifnum\tlines<3
\hangindent.25\textwidth
\hangafter\numexpr\tlines-3\relax
\fi\textbf{\textit{\lipsum[2]}}\par};
\end{tikzpicture}

\smallskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \shade node[preaction={fill=black,opacity=.5,},fill=yellow!35, inner sep=5mm, text width=.87\textwidth,align=justify]
  {%
\fontsize{12}{13}\selectfont
\leavevmode\smash{\raisebox{-2.5\baselineskip}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-c}}}\hfill
\parbox[t]{.75\textwidth}{%
\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}\textbf{%
\textcolor{red}{TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE (PART TO BE CENTERED)}}\strut
\par
\xdef\tlines{\the\prevgraf}}
\par
\vspace{\baselineskip}%
\ifnum\tlines<3
\hangindent.25\textwidth
\hangafter\numexpr\tlines-3\relax
\fi\textbf{\textit{\lipsum[2]}}\par};
\end{tikzpicture}


\smallskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \shade node[preaction={fill=black,opacity=.5,},fill=yellow!35, inner sep=5mm, text width=.87\textwidth,align=justify]
  {%
\fontsize{12}{13}\selectfont
\leavevmode\smash{\raisebox{-2.5\baselineskip}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-c}}}\hfill
\parbox[t]{.75\textwidth}{%
\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}\textbf{%
\textcolor{red}{TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE TITLE  TITLE TITLE TITLE  (PART TO BE CENTERED)}}\strut
\par
\xdef\tlines{\the\prevgraf}}
\par
\vspace{\baselineskip}%
\ifnum\tlines<3
\hangindent.25\textwidth
\hangafter\numexpr\tlines-3\relax
\fi
\textbf{\textit{\lipsum[2]}}\par};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the post, but unfortunately, it is not what I am looking for --- you have removed `\hangindent=\dimexpr 0.2\textwidth+\columnsep\relax
    \hangafter=-4` ; and for short titles such as the one provided, I want the text to wrap underneath the image; not start below the image. Also, I want to keep the paragraph text justified as it was previously. In others words, I am looking to keep everything as is in the first image, except that the last line of the title  be centered.

Comment: @mlchristians justification I'd already fixed that was just a tikz weirdness it sets ragged by default, but you were adding by hand padding `~\\` for titles so not automatic for different title lengths?  but you need to set the title as its own paragraph if you want to control its final line.

Comment: I added a cut in for short title cases @mlchristians

Comment: Thank you for the adjustments; however, it appears that removing `\newlength\drop \setlength\drop{15pt}` from the preamble, and also the two "drops" from the tikz code causes the beginning of the title to be pretty much flush with the top of the image instead of beginning 15pts below. With your revised codes, how may I adjust the beginning of the title back to where it was originally?

Comment: @mlchristians adjust the `\raisebox{-2.5\baselineskip}` to change the alignment of the title against the image but if you remove a baselineskip from there you'll need to check for 2 rather than 3 for the cutin, ie cutin at most one row not 0,1, or 2 as shown here. (just change the two `3` to `2`